# Trying to create an idempotent Cypher query

Tags: rest, neo4j, cypher, idempotent

So, I have been fighting cypher for the last week trying to get an idempotent query that deletes all of a type of node attached to a given root, then creates only as many nodes as are in the parameters. The problem is that either delete won't actually delete anything, or the nodes start multiplying at a dizzying rate every time I perform the query. One iteration managed to create over 10000 duplicate nodes before failing. I'm attempting to use this for a PUT request in a REST API. I'm working in Node.js with the Seraph library, but I'm just using the basic cypher query it provides.

Here's the most recent iteration of the query:

```
  var query = " MATCH (title:TITLE {sku: {sku}})" +
" OPTIONAL MATCH (title)-[r_GTIN]->(old_GTIN:GTIN)" +
" WITH title, r_GTIN, old_GTIN" +
" DELETE r_GTIN, old_GTIN" +
" WITH title" +
" CREATE (gtin:GTIN {gtins})" +
" MERGE (title)-[:has_GTIN]->(gtin);";
```

And here are example params:

```
{
sku: "ABC12345"
gtins: [{number: "999-999-999", type: "firstKind"},
        {number: "888-888-888", type: "secondKind"},
        {number: "777-777-777", type: "thirdKind"}]
}
```

I've tried more variations on this than I care to recount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to take your query and modify it slightly and have it execute what I think you are after.  The difference is after the nodes are deleted only the distinct title is passed onto the next clause in the query.

Without the `distinct` you pass potentially multiple matches of the same `title` node to the create clause in your query thus causing the same nodes to be created many times.

```
with [{number: "999-999-999", type: "firstKind"},
 {number: "888-888-888", type: "secondKind"},
 {number: "777-777-777", type: "thirdKind"}] as new_gtins
match (title:TITLE {sku: 'ABC12345'})
optional match title-[r:has_GTIN]->(gtin:GTIN)
delete r, gtin
with distinct title as title, new_gtins 
unwind new_gtins as new_gtin
create title-[:has_GTIN]->(gtin:GTIN {type: new_gtin.type, number: new_gtin.number})
```

Comment: That was it. Returning upwards of thousands of references to a single node is really non-obvious behavior...

Comment: yeah, agree, a bit subtle. I think if you just run the first match and return the data instead of deleting it will be more obvious... `match (title:TITLE {sku: 'ABC12345'})
optional match title-[r:has_GTIN]->(gtin:GTIN)
return title, r, gtin` and look at it in tabular form